# How do i resolve function not found in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, function, drupal-6, drupal-7

So I'm using the `queue_mail` module on Drupal 6 and everytime I call the function `queue_mail_send()`, drupal complains that it can't find the function...

I know that there's a code registry in Drupal 7, but what about Drupal 6? how do I get Drupal 6 to recognize that function instead of returning a fatal error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this out on a fresh drupal 6 install and it picked up the function for me. Just double check that the module is enabled and all of that good stuff.

Then, make sure that your `$message` array that is passed into `queue_mail_send($message = array())` function has these elements:

- [headers](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-2925) (array)

  - From
  - Reply-To
  - X-Mailer
- to
- subject
- body

For example, here's how I constructed my $message array:

```
$message = array(
  'to' => 'recipient@example.com',
  'subject' => 'example',
  'body' => 'hey', 
  'headers' => array(
    'From' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'Reply-To' => 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com',
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP',
  )
);
```